# Repairing Grub - Separate Partition - Dual Boot Windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, boot-repair

I am attempting to repair grub on separate /boot partition without removing Windows Boot Loader.

- I installed Ubuntu 12.04 after Windows 8 on 250GB SSD drive.
- Grub installation failed during Ubuntu Install on separate /boot partition (I chose to skip grub install after this happened)
- However, Grub does seem to be installed on that separate /boot partition. However, grub command line is loaded when I boot to it. I don't think there are any OS entries.
- I created a entry in Windows Boot Loader directly to Ubuntu OS partition, but it does same thing: grub command line.
- I am following instructions here with Live USB:

  - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System

**I'm worried that this command will overwrite MBR and Windows Boot Loader:**

> sudo grub-install /dev/sda

**I tried this, but it tells me that installing grub to a partition is not recommended:**

> sudo grub-install /dev/sda3

1. Do I even need to do an install?
2. Do I just need to update config with OS entries?
3. I've seen chroot mentioned.

Here is my fdisk -ls:

```
Device    Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      718847      358400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          718848   439648255   219464704    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       439648256   440135679      243712   83  Linux
/dev/sda4       440137726   488396799    24129537    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       440137728   480583679    20222976   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       480585728   488396799     3905536   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

*Any help is much appreciated!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just re-installing Ubuntu and did not include a separate /boot partition this time.  Grub installed to my Ubuntu partition and and Windows boots to that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try boot-repair ([installation guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)) program. In that program, select advanced options. It will help you you install grub manually where ever you want and also restore MBR. So I think you should install grub to sda and will be able to boot all OS from the GRUB menu.

Comment: boot-repair was extremely helpful, but in the end I just reinstalled Ubuntu and did not include a separate /boot partition this time.  Grub insatlled to my Ubuntu partition and and Windows boots to that.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, the dude here https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Restore_the_GRUB_Bootloader
Describers how to do what you want.  I too installed Ubuntu with /boot.

Comment: Perhaps you could include some steps that helped you to solve the same problem?